# With gurobi how can I constraint the domain of a variable in a set of value

Tags: python, gurobi

This is how I use `addVar` to add variable into the model:

```
my_set[j, t] = self.m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, lb=min_value, ub=max_value, name='test')
```

And this can only constraint the value as an integer falling between min_value and max_value, but actually I'd like to constraint the possible value in certain set of integers.
How can I make it?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the kind of integer sets you consider? Then it would be easier to describe an efficient approach? Where do these sets come from?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is directly possible (this is not possible in standard ILP, so maybe as an extension of gurobi), but you can add some constraints to your program. Assuming the variable you want to constrained is **y** and the set of variable is **D<sub>y</sub> = {v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ..., v<sub>|D<sub>y</sub>|</sub>}**, you could add the following **x<sub>i</sub>** variables and constraints:

- **y = x<sub>i</sub> for i in 1 ... |D<sub>y</sub>|**
- **sum (x<sub>i</sub> for i in 1 ... |D<sub>y</sub>|) = 1**
- **x<sub>i</sub> = 0 or 
  1**

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I've got too many variables in my model which nearly crack the memory. So maybe I'll consider adding a constraint to force the model getting value in my set.

Comment: @Jasonling The problem is that with such constraints you break some rules of ILP, so the optimizer will not be able to do optimization to find a solution faster. If you only have one variable with discrete values (and not a lot of values), you could try to solve the ILP for each of these values and keep the best solution. If you have lots of variables like that, you may want to consider other approaches such as CSP.